# Ind-objects with "full support"

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

[Now cross-posted to MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/452231/2126)

---

Let $C$ be a small category. Let's say a presheaf $P\colon C^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathsf{Set}$ has "full support" if $P(X)\neq \varnothing$ for all objects $X$. We could also say that $P$ is "inhabited everywhere".

Recall that an [Ind-object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object) on $C$ is a presheaf on $C$ which is a filtered colimit of representable presheaves. Equivalently, a presheaf is an Ind-object if and only if its [category of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_elements#The_category_of_elements_of_a_presheaf) is filtered (see Proposition 4.8 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object#recognition_of_indobjects)).

**Question:** Is there a nice characterization of those categories $C$ which admit an Ind-object with full support?

One characterization that comes from unwinding the definition is that there is a filtered diagram $D$ in $C$ such that every object in $C$ has an arrow to some object in $D$. But I'm wondering if there is some more "concrete" condition, i.e. one that doesn't involve quantifying over arbitrary filtered diagrams.

---

An obvious sufficient condition is that $C$ itself is filtered, since then the colimit of all representable presheaves by all arrows between them is an Ind-object with full support.

An obvious necessary condition is that $C$ is directed, in the sense that for all objects $X$ and $Y$ in $C$, there exists an object $Z$ in $C$ and arrows $X\to Z$ and $Y\to Z$. This follows from directedness of the category of elements of a presheaf of full support.

But neither of these conditions answer the question fully: I know examples of non-filtered $C$ which admit Ind-objects of full support, and of $C$ which are directed but admit no Ind-objects of full support.

---

Thanks to Sridhar Ramesh for providing the following example of a directed category with no Ind-object with full support.

Let $S$ be an uncountable set, and consider the free category $\newcommand{\C}{\mathscr{C}}\C$  generated by the directed graph $ (\mathcal{P}^{\mathrm{fin}}(S),\subset)$. So the objects of $\C$ are finite subsets of $S$, an arrow $A\to B$ is a finite chain $(A_0,\dots,A_n)$ with $n\geq 0$,  $A_0 = A$, $A_n = B$, and $A_i\subset A_{i+1}$ for all $i$ (note that $\subset$ means proper subset), and composition is concatenation of chains.

$\C$ is directed, since for any objects $A$ and $B$, we have arrows $(A,A\cup B)$ and $(B,A\cup B)$.

Observe that if we have a commutative square in $\C$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B\\
@VVV @VVV \\
C @>>> D
\end{CD}$$ then the composite arrow $A\to D$ is a chain containing both $B$ and $C$, so either $B\subseteq C$ or $C\subseteq B$.

Now suppose that $\newcommand{\D}{\mathscr{D}}\D\colon F\to \C$ is a filtered diagram, i.e. a functor from a filtered category $F$ to $\C$.

Let $x\in F$, and write ${\uparrow}(x)$ for the set of objects in $F$ which admit an arrow from $x$. Given $y,z\in {\uparrow}(x)$, since $F$ is filtered, there is a commutative square in $F$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
x @>>> y\\
@VVV @VVV \\
z @>>> w
\end{CD}$$
It follows that $\D(y)$ and $\D(z)$ are comparable under $\subseteq$. So $\D({\uparrow}(x))$ is linearly ordered by $\subseteq$. Now  distinct elements of $\D({\uparrow}(x))$ must have different finite cardinalities, so $\D({\uparrow}(x))$ is countable, and $\bigcup \D({\uparrow}(x))$ is a countable subset of $S$. If $s\in S\setminus \bigcup \D({\uparrow}(x))$, then $\{s\}$ does not admit an arrow into any object in $\D({\uparrow}(x))$. Since $F$ is filtered, it follows that $\{s\}$ does not admit an arrow into any object in $\D(F)$. Thus the Ind-object corresponding to $\D$ does not have full support.

A similar argument shows that the free category generated by the directed graph $(\omega_1,<)$ is directed but admits no Ind-object with full support.

Comment: It suffices to find a small filtered category $D$ and a surjective-on-objects functor $D \to C$, right? But if $C$ is directed then this always exists: basically take $D$ to be a certain poset whose elements are finite trees in $C$ and the functor $D \to C$ to be the one sending a tree to its root.

Comment: @ZhenLin In which way would $D$ be a poset? In the subtree relation, I can't see how the functor would be well-defined on arrows (assuming the image arrow would be the path root to root). If you meant something different, please disregard this, but I'd like to know the details.

Comment: Ah, I think I see my error. Somehow I imagined $D$ itself would be a tree (and so there would be no question of well-definedness).

Comment: I initially thought directedness would be a characterization, with the same sort of idea you suggested in your first comment. The mistake was pointed out to me by Sridhar Ramesh, who also provided a counterexample. I'll edit a version of his counterexample into the question. @ZhenLin

Comment: I don't follow your argument. You have found for each $x$ an $s$ such that etc., but that $s$ depends on $x$, right? So how do you conclude that there is an $s$ such that for all $x$ etc.? I still think there is a construction of a filtered category (a directed poset, even) $D$ and a surjective-on-objects functor $D \to C$ when $C$ is directed, but the construction is too fiddly to write in the comment box...

Comment: @ZhenLin The $\{s\}$ obtained from the argument has no arrow to any object in $D(F)$. Suppose there is an arrow $\{s\}\to D(y)$. Since F is directed, there is a $z\in{\uparrow}(x)$ with an arrow $f\colon y\to z$. Composing with $D(f)$ gives an arrow $\{s\}\to D(z)$, contradiction.

Comment: I think I see what’s happening now. This is an instructive example of the difference between directed and filtered…